# Intel Graphics card

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my Thinkpad with intel HD 4600 graphics card When i tried to check additional driver it says no additional driver found. output of this command,

```
apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel* | grep Installed
 Installed: (none)
  Installed: (none)
  Installed: (none)
  Installed: (none)
  Installed: (none)
  Installed: (none)
  Installed: (none)
  Installed: (none)
  Installed: 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.6
  Installed: (none)
  Installed: (none)
  Installed: (none)

output of this command lshw -c video is
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

I dont want to overload my CPU. I want to use my laptop to play mid range game using steam. Do  i need to install driver for graphics card using intel graphic installer? oibaf ? x-swat?I dont exactly know what is xorg or mesa utils and if it is neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install any drivers for this graphics adapter.

The driver is already installed in Ubuntu by default.

You can see that you have `i915` kernel module and `xserver-xorg-video-intel` user space driver.